# $PGL(n, F)=PSL(n, F)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, linear-groups

$PGL(n, F)$ and $PSL(n, F)$ are isomorphic if and only if every element of $F$ has an $n$th root in $F$. ($F$ is a finite field.)

I can show that if  $PGL(n, F)=PSL(n, F)$ then $|F|$ have to be even. I have not any idea how to deal with it. Any suggestions?

Comment: If $F$ is the field of 3 elements, then every element of $F$ has a cube root in $F$, so I don't understand how you get that the order of $F$ is even.

Comment: So for example ${\rm PSL}(3,3) = {\rm PGL}(3,3)$. In any case, $|F|$ even makes no sense if $F$ is infinite.

Comment: I have read this assertion from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_linear_group

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The determinant map gives rise to a split exact sequence

$$ PSL(n, F) \hookrightarrow PGL(n,F) \twoheadrightarrow F^\times / (F^\times)^n, $$

i.e. we have an isomorphism $PSL(n,F) \rtimes  F^\times / (F^\times)^n \cong PGL(n,F)$.

Now, $F^\times / (F^\times)^n = 1$, if and only if every element of $F$ has a $n$-th root.

Comment: Sorry, I still have difficulty understanding the other direction, if $F^\times /(F^\times)^n \neq  1$, how can we know that $PSL(n,F)$ is not isomorphic to $PGL(n,F)$?